# spring+elaticsearch @Document annotation，shards attribute dynamic assignment

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a 10 billion data, and now I have to divide it into 12 indexes by month, so if you use springboot+spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch, @Document annotated indexName, shards must implement dynamic assignment, now indexName is OK Dynamic assignment, as shown in the following code:

```
@Bean
public DocumentConfig documentConfig() {
    return new DocumentConfig();
}

@Document(
         indexName = "#{documentConfig.getIndexName() == 
             null?'jan':documentConfig.getIndexName()}",
          type = "_doc",
          shards = 3,
          replicas = 1
     )
```

and Switch index like this:

```
documentConfig.setIndexName(name);
es.save(obj);
```

But when I create a new index, shards will become the default value of 5.
When I try to change it dynamically like the following code, it gives an error:Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to short

```
shards = "#{documentConfig.getShards() == null? 
    3:documentConfig.getShards()}"
```

How to deal with it? Thank you

Comment: Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Looking forward to the emergence of experts

Comment: Having this issue as well

Answer (score 0):

[image]

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearc.misc.index.settings

in spring-data-elasticsearch, create es index by Entity(annotioned @Document pojo),   you can custom index detail by @Setting,@Mapping,  whitch need providier a settings file in you classpath.